# Explorer image thumbnails are grey/incomplete/partial

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

**[2 months later]**
I haven't found any other sources addressing this problem. And it's still happening.
Doing this update/edit to possible catch someone's eye and get some suggestions?

**[Original]**
I have recently noticed a problem on my Win7 x64 Home machine. When navigating the pictures library, I run across a fair amount of thumbnails that are grey and only partially rendered. This is *not* not the absence of thumbnails caused by "always show icons, never thumbnails" checkbox, and is a local drive, have seen *many* other posts for those issues...

I've run `cleanmgr` for thumbnails, and also manually deleted the `.db` files from `%LOCALAPPADAT%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`.

That did actually fix *one* thumbnail once (while preparing this post) but in general it doesn't work.

Why do specialized imaging programs *not* have this problem, but Explorer does? How do you fix Explorer? It's very annoying!

[image: grey thumb]

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem for two years for pics transferred from my old Canon camera. And I just found a solution: Disable the codec "MJPEG decompressor". Which is simply done by running the free application [NIRsoft InstalledCodec](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/installed_codec.html), right clicking "MJPEG decompressor" and select "Disable". Done! I think the thumbnails load faster now as well!

For me this is a solution since I never use MJPEG anyway. If you do use MJPEG videos I don't have a solution tried out but I think you can download e g the free codec pack "[K-Lite Mega](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_mega_codec_pack.htm)" and then use ffdshow, or the free image viewer "[IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/faq.htm#PAGE8)" (and use DirectShow).

A bit weird how a Microsoft codec is the problem. And how an MPJPEG codec affects JPEG. Maybe the problem is not the codec itself but some conflict, what do I know. And Uninstalling IrfanView (and reinstalling it) didn't help for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, years later, and this question kept coming up on google. So here's another fix that worked for me. Reinstall the program that handles thumbnails, then delete the caches.

In my case, I simply re-installed Irfanview, my image viewing application. All thumbnails generate properly.

The original problem may have been caused by installing a second image viewing application and switching back to Irfanview as my default program. (The default program generates the thumbnails / detailed info / preview page images.

Comment: I'm using Windows Explorer, not Irfanview.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by uninstalling the update windows 7 KB 2670838
cleanmgr for thumbnails, and manually deleted the. db files from in my case it does not work

Comment: Is this an answer to the original question, or are you commenting that you have the same problem which a fix did not work?